# Amazon Athena Convert String to Date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am looking to convert the following string: **mmm-dd-yyyy** to a date: **yyyy-mm-dd**

e.g

**Nov-06-2015 to 2015-11-06**

within Amazon Athena

Comment: Have you looked into the [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html) function? For example, try something like: `SELECT date_parse(d, '%b-%d-%Y')`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would do date_parse. Adjust your regex accordingly.

```
select date_parse('Nov-06-2015','%b-%d-%Y')
```

2015-11-06 00:00:00.000

refd:https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 8):

You can also use **cast** function to get desire output as date type.

```
select cast(date_parse('Nov-06-2015','%M-%d-%Y') as date);
```

output--2015-11-06

in amazon athena
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html
used date parse to parse string and cast to convert **2015-11-06 00:00:00.000**
into **2015-11-06**

Comment: Are '%M' and '%b' equivalent for the `date_parse` pattern?