# Converting Timestamp from String to Date in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

What is the best way to convert a timestamp in a string format '2022/09/02 16:55:14.077' to a date format in Athena?

Comment: Have you tried using [cast with date_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152596/amazon-athena-convert-string-to-date#:~:text=can%20also%20use-,cast,-function%20to%20get)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon Athena Convert String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152596/amazon-athena-convert-string-to-date)

Comment: Can you post the error or expected outputs that you want ?